# How do I customize the look/feel of my lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, customization

I have a Samsung Droid Charge (running 2.2) and it comes with two lock screen slider styles: Glass and Puzzle. Is there any way to get additional styles? I've done quite a bit of searching but haven't found anything.

**Note that I'm not looking for an app. I'm specifically looking for more system styles, if they exist.**

Do they exist?

Answer (score 3):

Try [WidgetLocker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker), it's very customizable and my favorite.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WidgetLocker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker) as [@onik](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/475/onik) said, but if you search for "lock screen" at the Android Market you will have a lot of alternatives, like for example [WP7Lock](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.futuredreams.wp7.lockscreen)